# First occurrence except escaped chars in C

Tags: c, string, strchr

How can I locate the first `unescaped` char in a str. In the following code, I get the first char at position 14, but I'm looking the one at position 26.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
  char str[] = "FOO + pHWAx \\\"bar AER/2.1\" BAZ";
  printf ("%s\n",str);
  char * pch;
  pch=strchr(str,'"');
  printf ("found at %d\n",pch-str+1);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: By any chance, this would not happen to be homework, where it is dictated that `strchr` must be used?

Comment: @Kaz: thanks! no, I just thought `strchr` would perform better with large strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `strpbrk` function to look for the first occurence of any one of several characters at once. You  must not skip the escape character; you must check whether it is followed by the character that you're really looking for.

I.e. suppose we want to look for `"` which can be escaped as `\"`. Actually, this means we must look for either `"` or `\`.  In other words:

```
char *ptr = strpbrk(string, "\"\\"); /* look for chars in the set { ", \ } */
```

But we have to do this in a loop, because we are not interested in escaped quotes and have to keep going:

```
char *quote = 0;
char *string = str; /* initially points to the str array */

while (*string != 0) {
  char *ptr = strpbrk(string, "\"\\");
```

Next we check whether we found something:

```
  if (!ptr)
    break;
```

If we found something is is necessarily a `\` or `"`:

```
  if (*ptr == '"') {
    quote = ptr;
    break;
  }
```

If it is not a quote, then it must be an escape. We increment to the next character. If it is a terminating null it means we have a backslash at the end of a string: an improper escape.

```
  if (*++ptr == 0)
    break;
```

Otherwise, we can skip the next character and continue the loop to scan for the next escape or unescaped quote.

```
  string = ++ptr;
}
```

If an unescaped quote occurs, then `quote` points to it after the execution of the while loop. Otherwise `quote` remains null.

This code assumes that there exist other escapes besides `\"`, but that they are all one character long, e.g. `\b` or `\r`.  It will not work if there are longer escapes like `\xff`.  Escapes constitute the conventions of a language: you have to know what the language is that you're processing to do it correctly.

Comment: Trivia: the terminology "break" (`strpbrk`, pointer to break) and "span" (`strspn`, `strcspn`) come from the pattern functions BREAK and SPAN in the text processing language SNOBOL.

Comment: wouldn't `string = ++ptr;` need to be `string = ptr + 2;` so it skips the quote?

Comment: Yes sorry, that is buggy. I will fix it.